# Why is it that the level curves of $g$ are orthogonal to these curves of $f$ here?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f, g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable functions such that $g_x = f_y$ and $g_y = -f_x$. The flux lines of $f$ are defined to be the curves that are orthogonal to the level curves of $f$. Why is it that the level curves of $g$ are the flux lines of $f$?

I know it has everything to do with the fact that the gradient is orthogonal to level curves, but I haven't quite been able to formulate an airtight proof yet. I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: What is $\nabla f\cdot\nabla g$?

Comment: $0$. Can't see exactly where it will help me yet.

Comment: Because the level curves of $g$ are orthogonal to $\nabla g$ and the flux lines of $f$ are *parallel* to $\nabla f$. But being orthogonal to $\nabla g$ means you're in the direction of ...

Comment: Being orthogonal to $\nabla g$ means I'm parallel to $\nabla f$... and it's done. Ugh I hate when I miss the obvious. Thank you.

Comment: Hope you're making good progress! ;)

Comment: I am indeed! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the gradient vectors $$< f_x, f_y>$$ and    $$< g_x, g_y>$$ are perpendicular to each other.

That implies that the level curves meet at a $ 90$ degrees angle.

Thus the level curves of one is the flux curves of the other.

Comment: Just curious, do you use `<` instead of `\langle` for stylistic purposes?